# Is there any way I can deserialize BigQuery Numeric datatype using gson

Tags: json, serialization, google-bigquery, gson, google-cloud-dataflow

While Deserialising BigQuery object to custom object I'm facing below issue. So I'm using BigQuery Storage API to fetch Bigquery result. Below is the code for the same.

```
BigQueryIO.read(new ReadTable<Payments>(Payments.class)).from("TableName")
                                .withMethod(Method.DIRECT_READ)
```

As you can see inside ReadTable class I'm deserialising objects using gson.

```
gson.fromJson(jsonElement, class1);
```

Below is the code for custom pojo class, Just the getter and setter and I want that field data in String format.

```
private @Nullable String amount;
public String getAmount() {
return amount;
    }
    public void setAmount(String amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }
```

[image: getting this error while deserialising Numeric Object]

Is there any way I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Did you find a workaround for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it may be a bug, but we may be able to work around it. I suspect that the ByteBuffer can be parsed as BigDecimal. Can you try something like this:

```
new BigDecimal(theByteBuffer.toCharBuffer().array()
```

or if `BigInteger` will work:

```
new BigInteger(theByteBuffer.array()
```

Let me know if that works at all, or if we should iterate to figure out how to di this.